# Android GPS ACCURACY_HIGH causes force close?

Tags: android

I am working on a GPS portion and for criteria, I can set the accuracy to ACCURACY_FINE, ACCURACY_MEDIUM etc. However, for some reason I keep getting a force close error If i set it the Criteria to ACCURACY_HIGH. any ideas on what might be causing it?

Heres my Manifest, im pretty sure everything is ok, since I am able to use different Criterias:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Here are my logs:

```
 07-05 08:51:48.641: W/dalvikvm(1040): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jetdelivery.mobile/com.jetdelivery.mobile.statuspage}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: accuracy=3
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: accuracy=3
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at android.location.Criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.java:223)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at com.jetdelivery.mobile.statuspage.onCreate(statuspage.java:125)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
 07-05 08:51:48.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):    ... 11 more
```

I am developing using Android 2.3.5 firmware. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The android [Criteria](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html) has two separate groups of accuracy constants. `ACCURACY_FINE` and `ACCURACY_COARSE` are for general location, while `ACCURACY_LOW`, `ACCURACY_MEDIUM`, and `ACCURACY_HIGH` "may be used for horizontal, altitude, speed or bearing accuracy." If you are talking about general GPS location you should use coarse or fine.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I am using ACCURACY_HIGH incorrectly. I would like to ask you why ACCURACY_MEDIUM works for me, but ACCURACY_HIGH doesnt?

Comment: `ACCURACY_MEDIUM` is `0x00000002` so is `ACCURACY_COARSE`; `ACCURACY_LOW` is `0x00000001` so is `ACCURACY_FINE`.

Whereas `ACCURACY_HIGH` is `0x00000003`

Comment: That's true, but just because they are constants with equivalent values doesn't mean you should use the wrong one... that path leads to confusion and unreadability. COARSE and FINE are meant for general location, while the others are meant for altitude, speed, etc.

Answer (score 18):

To clarify matt5784's answer a little more, here's an example of how to use the new constants:

```
    //All your normal criteria setup
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    //Use FINE or COARSE (or NO_REQUIREMENT) here
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(true);

    //API level 9 and up
    criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
    criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
    criteria.setBearingAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
    criteria.setSpeedAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ACCURACY_FINE` is grouped with `ACCURACY_COARSE` with constant values of 1 & 2 respectively. `ACCURACY_LOW`, `MEDIUM` and `HIGH` are grouped together with constant values 1, 2 & 3.

It seems that setAccuracy expects and returns either `COARSE` or `FINE`, while setVerticalAccuracy, setHorizontalAccuracy, setSpeedAccuracy and setBearingAccuracy expect `LOW`, `MEDIUM` or `HIGH`. Furthermore, when you call setAccuracy, it sets horizontal accuracy like so:

```
public void setAccuracy(int accuracy) {
    if (accuracy < NO_REQUIREMENT || accuracy > ACCURACY_COARSE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("accuracy=" + accuracy);
    }
    if (accuracy == ACCURACY_FINE) {
        mHorizontalAccuracy = ACCURACY_HIGH;
    } else {
        mHorizontalAccuracy = ACCURACY_LOW;
    }
}
```

So, use `ACCURACY_FINE`. I agree this should be better documented.